# How to find documents with exactly the same array entries as in a query

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have documents in a collection, looking like this:

```
[
  {
    userId: 1,
    itemsIds: [399957190, 366369952],
    hash: '85e765840b1cd3c413404cdf6b8fb2a4'
  },
  {
    userId: 2,
    itemsIds: [349551151, 366369952],
    hash: 'a28fa334515749b1b13fcd2183edb8de'
  },
  {
    userId: 3,
    itemsIds: [399957190, 366369952],
    hash: '85e765840b1cd3c413404cdf6b8fb2a4'
  }

]
```

These are users, which have favorite items in their lists. I want one user's list to others and find if they are equal. If they are, I want to mark them as a kind of a pair in my code and perform some actions.

In the example above users 1 and 3 have the same favorites lists.
How do I find users with an array which contains exactly the values I list?

Comment: MongoDB itself if schemaless, so you won't find any such feature there. You can try ODM ( Object Document Mapper aka ORM for document ) products to handle this, but it comes with it's own catch that you **need** all the data resident in order to create a "hash" over the joined results. Not really wise. To what end may I ask do you deem this necessary? What is the real goal here? Please edit in your question to explain. Long comments are for people like me to ask. Your question is for long details and not comments.

Comment: The goal is to save the time not having to go through the whole array and compare it to my search criteria array. Does it make sense?

Comment: Nope. No sense at all. Perhaps if you explained what you "think" you need to do in a "search" then we can inform you better as to what you really "need". Editing question and explaining please. What you "think" you want as an answer is not practical. I already have several "guesses" to what you really "need".

Comment: I'd expect a *database index* would be more useful here?! See http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/eq/#eq-match-array-value

Comment: I have added more details, please have a look.

Comment: So is that the "real" question here. How to "pair" users with the same common "itemIds"? If so, is "partial" also useful to you? As I can see very useful cases for that as well, and no implementation invoves a "hash".

Comment: Yeah, probably I am trying to fight the problem at the wrong end.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are several "very useful cases" here where in fact trying to create a "unique hash" over the array content is actually "getting in the way" of the myriad of problems that can be easily addressed.

### Finding Common to "Me"

If you for example take "user 1" from the sample provided, and consider that you have that data loaded already and want to find "those in common with me"  by the matched "itemsIds" from what the current user object has, then there are two simple query approaches:

1. **Find "exactly" the same:** Is where you want to inspect other user data to see those users that have the same "exact" interests. This is simple and "unordered" usage of the [**`$all`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/all/) query operator:

   ```js
   db.collection.find({ 
       "itemsIds": { "$all": [399957190, 366369952] },
       "userId": { "$ne": 1 }
   })
   ```

   Which is going to return "user 3" since they are the one with "both" common "itemsIds" entries. Order is not important here as it is always a match in any order, as long as they are both there. This is another form of `$and` as query arguments.
2. **Find "similar" in common to me":** Which is basically asking *"do you have something that is the same?"*. For that you can use the [**`$in`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) query operator. It will match if "either" of the specified conditions is met:

   ```js
   db.collection.find({ 
       "itemsIds": { "$in": [399957190, 366369952] },
       "userId": { "$ne": 1 }
   })
   ```

   In this case "both" the "user 2" and "user 3" are going to match, as they "at least" share "one" of the conditions specified and that means that have "something in common" with the source data of the query.

   This is in fact another form of the `$or` query operator, and just like before it is a lot simplier and concise to write this way given the conditions to be applied.

### Finding Common "Things"

There are also cases where you might want to find things "in common" without having a base "user" to start from. So how do you tell that "user 1" and "user 2" share the same "itemIds", or in fact that various of the users might share the same "itemIds" value individually, but who are they?

1. **Get the exact matches:** Is of course where you look at the "itemsIds" values and [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) them together. Generally the "order is important" here, so optimally you have them "pre-ordered" and consistently always to make this as simple as:

   ```js
   db.collection.aggregate([
       { "$group": {
           "_id": "$itemsIds",
           "common": { "$push": "$userId" }
       }}
   ])
   ```

   And that is all there really is to it, as long as the order is already there. If not, then you can do a slightly longer winded form to do the "ordering", but the same could be said of generating a "hash":

   ```js
   db.collection.aggregate([
       { "$unwind": "$itemsIds" },
       { "$sort": { "_id": 1, "itemsIds": 1 } },
       { "$group": {
           "_id": "$_id",
           "userId": { "$first": "$userId" },
           "itemsIds": { "$push": "$itemsIds" }
       }},
       { "$group": {
           "_id": "$itemsIds",
           "common": { "$push": "$userId" }
       }}
   ])
   ```

   Not "super" performant, but it makes the point of why you always keep ordered on addition of array entries. Which is a very simple process.
2. **Common "user" to "items":** Which is another simple process abstracting on above with "breaking down" the array under `$unwind`, and then basically grouping back:

   ```js
   db.collection.aggregate([
       { "$unwind": "$itemsIds" },
       { "$group": {
           "_id": "$itemsIds",
           "users": { "$addToSet": "$userId" }
       }}
   ])
   ```

   And again, just a simple grouping aggregator of [**`$addToSet`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addToSet/) does the job and collects the "distinct userId" values for each "itemsIds" value.

These are all basic solutions, and I could go on with "set intersections" and what not, but this is the "primer".

Don't try to compute a "hash", MongoDB has a good "arsenal" for matching the entries anyway. Use it and "abuse it" as well, until it breaks. Then try harder.

Comment: Thank you for the great comprehensive answer!