# Managing database with content-addressable hash

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to write a way to `insert` and `find`. I simple want to be able to insert any piece of content like a `string` or `json`. I'd like to find the content by a hash of the content, I have a `getHash()` `function` that generates the hash for the content.

This is what I want:

```
// insert(user, dataType, data, dataName)
insert('thomasreggi', 'example', {'foo': 'bar'}, 'document.json')

// find(user, dataType, hash)
var hash = getHash({'foo': 'bar'})
find('thomasreggi', 'example', hash)
```

This is what I currently have:

```
/* global db */

function insert (user, dataType, data, dataName) {
  var content = {}
  content.type = dataType
  content.data = data
  content.name = dataName
  content.hash = util.getHash(data)
  content.date = new Date()
  var users = db.collection('users')
  return users.updateAsync({
    'service.user': user
  }, {
    '$push': {'content': content}
  }).then(function () {
    return content
  })
}

function find (user, dataType, dataHash) {
  var users = db.collection('users')
  return users.aggregateAsync(
    {$match: {'service.user': user}},
    {$unwind: '$content'},
    {$project: {content: 1}},
    {$match: {
      'content.type': dataType,
      'content.hash': dataHash
    }},
    {$sort: {'content.date': -1}},
    {$limit: 1}
  ).then(function (content) {
    if (!content || content.length === 0) return false
    return content
  })
}
```

- This stores the content in the `user` collection, should this be stored in a `content` collection?
- This doesn't utilize a content-addressed `hash`, meaning if two pieces of content are inserted they will be duplicated.
- I would like a way to `push` a `new Date` every time a piece of content is updated.
- I would like a way to `push` the updated name if a new `dataName` is supplied to a piece of content that already exists.

Example:

The following code should create the following document

```
insert('thomasreggi', 'example', {'foo': 'bar'}, 'alpha.json')
insert('thomasreggi', 'example', {'foo': 'bar'}, 'beta.json')

{
  type: 'example'
  data: {'foo': 'bar'}
  hash: getHash({'foo': 'bar'}) // value of hash
  date: [
    new Date(), // first date
    new Date() // second date
  ]
  name: [
    'alpha.json',
    'beta.json'
  ]
}
```

However when the same name is applied the date of the second insert should be pushed.

```
insert('thomasreggi', 'example', {'foo': 'bar'}, 'alpha.json')
insert('thomasreggi', 'example', {'foo': 'bar'}, 'alpha.json')

{
  type: 'example'
  data: {'foo': 'bar'}
  hash: getHash({'foo': 'bar'}) // value of hash
  date: [
    new Date(), // first date
    new Date() // second date
  ]
  name: [
    'alpha.json'
  ]
}
```

Update:

Here's my first stab at the insert function

```
function insert (user, type, data, name) {
  var hash = util.getHash(data)
  var collection = db.collection('content')
  return collection.find({
    'user': user,
    'type': type,
    'hash': hash,
    'meta.name': name
  }).toArray().then(function (arr) {
    if (!arr.length) {
      return collection.find({
        'user': user,
        'type': type,
        'hash': hash
      }).toArray().then(function (arr) {
        if (!arr.length) {
          return collection.insert({
            'user': user,
            'type': type,
            'hash': hash,
            'date': new Date(),
            'data': data,
            'meta': [
              {
                'name': name
                'date': new Date()
              }
            ],
          })
        } else {
          return collection.update({
            'user': user,
            'type': type,
            'hash': hash,
            'meta.name': name
          }, {
            '$push': {
              'meta': {
                'name': name
                'date': new Date()
              }
            }
          })
        }
      })
    } else {
      return collection.update({
        'user': user,
        'type': type,
        'hash': hash,
        'meta.name': name
      }, {
        '$push': {
          'meta': {
            'date': new Date()
          }
        }
      })
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: Hmmn, I answered [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32435869/how-to-find-documents-with-exactly-the-same-array-entries-as-in-a-query/32436787#32436787) just recently where the question was originally titled and proposed to "hash" content in a similar way to what  you are proposing. Perhaps the answer is very much the same in basic principles?

Comment: Thanks @BlakesSeven, I don't really think that that question needs Hashes like you allude to. Do you think that's my case as well. I'm having a bit of trouble seeing the corollary. I need to be able to have hashed content but also push the meta information like name and date.

Comment: Well my point in raising that to you was that "most" cases do not need a "hash" and are better off using the native query operators. Your "simplified" example here would suggest it falls under the same basic conditions, unless you have a "larger" case to expand on in your question with an edit?

Comment: Just to expand a little more, I'm inserting parsed csv files so the content can be large and I only want it stored once, so if it's inserted multiple times I don't want to have to store it twice. However if the name of the file a user uploads changes from `alpha.csv` to `beta.csv` I want to track those changes and have a history of what the file used to be named. For these reasons the metadata + content hash seem appropriate.