# Minimize long mongo statement

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

The reason this mongo insert is so long and takes 5 calls is outlined [here (Managing database with content-addressable hash)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32462389/managing-database-with-content-addressable-hash), I'm looking to make this make more sense / not be so verbose. Is there a feature I'm missing to allow me to conditionally upsert based on if a value is in array.

```
function insert (user, type, data, name) {
  var hash = util.getHash(data)
  var collection = db.collection('content')
  return collection.find({
    'user': user,
    'type': type,
    'hash': hash,
    'meta.name': name
  }).toArray().then(function (arr) {
    if (!arr.length) {
      return collection.find({
        'user': user,
        'type': type,
        'hash': hash
      }).toArray().then(function (arr) {
        if (!arr.length) {
          return collection.insert({
            'user': user,
            'type': type,
            'hash': hash,
            'date': new Date(),
            'data': data,
            'meta': [
              {
                'name': name
                'date': new Date()
              }
            ],
          })
        } else {
          return collection.update({
            'user': user,
            'type': type,
            'hash': hash,
            'meta.name': name
          }, {
            '$push': {
              'meta': {
                'name': name
                'date': new Date()
              }
            }
          })
        }
      })
    } else {
      return collection.update({
        'user': user,
        'type': type,
        'hash': hash,
        'meta.name': name
      }, {
        '$push': {
          'meta': {
            'date': new Date()
          }
        }
      })
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: You could use some named functions rather than defining all your callbacks as anonymous in line functions.

Comment: @bhspencer Your totally right. I'd really like to not have this many calls in the first place, this code was more to demonstrate the outcome I'm looking for an alternative within MongoDB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one call, the only problem with it is that it will update the `name` every time, I'd like it to not update the `name` if the `name` exists in the `meta` array.

```
function insert (user, type, data, name) {
  var content = {
    'user': user,
    'data': data,
    'hash': util.getHash(data),
    'date': new Date()
  }
  var collection = db.collection('contents')
  return collection.update({
    'user': content.user,
    'type': content.type
  }, {
    '$setOnInsert': content,
    '$push': {
      'meta': {
        'name': name,
        'date': new Date()
      }
    }
  }, {
    'upsert': true
  })
}
```